# How to get file name on server side that was uploaded on client side in GWT?

Tags: excel, gwt

I have made a project where i read data from Excel on server side and pass it to client side, to get displayed. To do so I used to read excel file on my system by following command:

clien-object.setInputFile("c://file-name.xls");

But now i want user to upload an excel file and i should be able to read it.
to do so i need file name and path to be put into the double quotes above.

Please tell me how to get file name and path of the file that i uploaded using FileUpload()  ????

Answer (score 0):

**How to get file name that is uploaded using [FileUpload](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html)?**

Steps to follow:

- Get the file name that is to be uploaded using FileUpload

  ```
  FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
  ...
  String fileName= fileUpload.getFilename();
  ```
- Just append the file name in the Form's Action itself as Query string

  ```
  FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
  ...
  form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"formSubmit?fileName="+fileName);
  form.submit(); // submit the form
  ```
- At the server side (Servlet/JSP) just get the file name from Query string from HTTP request

  ```
  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws 
           ServletException, IOException {
           String fileName= req.getParameter("fileName");
           ...
  }
  ```

Please have a look at the sample code on [GWT - FileUpload Widget](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_fileupload_widget.htm).